# Redirection after ajax form Submission from the client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Hi i am new to nodejs and ajax i m trying to submit a form into database and then set some session variables and then redirect to another page my ajax code on the client side is

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                        /* attach a submit handler to the form */
                        $("#comp").submit(function(event) {

                          /* stop form from submitting normally */
                          event.preventDefault();

                          /* get some values from elements on the page: */
                          var $form = $( this ),
                          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

                          /* Send the data using post */
                          var posting = $.post( url, { N1: $('#N1').val(), N2: $('#N2').val(), N3: $('#N3').val(), N4: $('#N4').val()
                          , N5: $('#N5').val(), N6: $('#N6').val(), N7: $('#N7').val(), N8: $('#N8').val(), N9: $('#N9').val() } );

                          /* Alerts the results */
                          posting.done(function( data ) {
                            alert('success');
                            window.location.assign("localhost:3000/User_Creation");
                          });


                        });
                    </script>
```

and my server side code is as follows i don't know if this is the proper way to do it or not so correct me if i m doing this the wrong way i m putting my whole server file i don't know where i am going wrong

```
var express = require('express');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
var assert = require('assert');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var session = require("express-session");
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);



users = [];
connections = []
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({resave: true, saveUninitialized: true, secret:'iasugdhasjb981234781924789', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
    if(!req.session.userId)
    {
        res.render('index.ejs');
    }
    else
    {
        res.redirect('/welcome');
    }
});



app.post('/index', function (req, res) {
        var N1 = req.body.firstname;
        var N2 = req.body.lastname;
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        db.collection('OB').find({user_name:N1},{password:N2}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
            throw err;
        }});
    });
});
var resultArray = [];
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var N1 = req.body.N1;
    var N2 = req.body.N2;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
        throw err;
        }
        db.collection('OB').find({user_name:N1,password:N2}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            resultArray=result;
            try{
                req.session.userId = result[0]._id;
                req.session.userType = result[0].type;
                if(result[0].type=="root")
                {
                    res.redirect('/New_Company');
                }
                else
                {
                    res.redirect('/welcome');
                }
            }
            catch(e){
                res.redirect('/404_Error');
            }

        });
    });
});

app.get('/404_Error',function(req, res){
    res.render('404_Error.ejs');
});

app.get('/New_Company',function(req, res){
    if(!req.session.userType){
        res.redirect('/404_Error');
    }
    else{
        res.render('create_company.ejs');
    }

});

app.post('/New_Company',function(req, res){
    if(!req.session.userType){
        res.redirect('/404_Error');
    }
    if(req.session.userType!="root"){
        res.redirect('/404_Error');
    }
    var item = {
        company_name: req.body.N1,
        Comp_currency: req.body.N2,
        start_time: req.body.N3,
        end_time: req.body.N4,
        comp_country: req.body.N5,
        phone_no: req.body.N6,
        total_locations: req.body.N7,
        time_zone: req.body.N8
    };/*
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
                  if (err) {
                    throw err;
                  }
                  db.collection('company').find({company_name:req.body.N1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                      throw err;
                    }
                    res.redirect('/404_Error');
                 });
            });
    mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection('company').insertOne(item, function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Item inserted');
            db.close();
            MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
                  if (err) {
                    throw err;
                  }
                  db.collection('company').find({company_name:req.body.N1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                      throw err;
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                    req.session.comp_id = result[0]._id;
                    res.redirect('/User_Creation');     
                 });
            });
        });
    });*/
    console.log('Successfully Executed');
});

app.get('/User_Creation', function(req, res){
    res.render('create_user.ejs');
});

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/index');
});

app.get('/welcome',function(req, res){
    if(!req.session.userId)
    {
        res.redirect('/404_Error');
    }
    else
    {
        res.render('login.ejs',{resultArray:resultArray,id:req.session.userId});
    }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('DEFAULT PAGE');
});

app.get('/location', function(req, res){
  res.render('location_details.ejs');
});

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log('Connected :%s sockets connected',connections.length);

    socket.on('disconnect',function(data){
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket),1);
        console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets connected',connections.length);
    });

    socket.on('send message',function(data){
        console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('new message',{msg:data});      
    });
});
server.listen(3000);
console.log("running");
```

thanks....

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: not redirecting to the page browser giving error ADDRESS WASNT UNDERSTOOD

Comment: does the alert get fired?

Comment: yes alert gets fired

Comment: Try to add http to the url.

Comment: it works thanks jcubic

Answer (score 0):

Add `http` at the beginning of the URL:

```
window.location.assign("http://localhost:3000/User_Creation");
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Brett :-).